# What are the standard places that Java Virtual Machine is configured on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: java

I'm running Pangolin (12.04 LTS) and want to sort out some Java stuff where my JVM is pointing at a different place to my Compiler.

To demonstrate, my JVM is as follows:

```
pcrow@pcrow-HP-notebook:~/Documents$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Whereas my Compiler points here:

```
pcrow@pcrow-HP-notebook:~/Documents$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_51
```

I have configured the latter through adding an entry to my `~/.profile` file. The thing is that I'm not sure what sets the former and I want them to be consistent. In '/etc/environment' I have the following entry:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

And when I run `printenv | grep "java"`

```
PATH=/usr/share/maven/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Can you tell me where IcedTea6 is most likely set up on Ubuntu? I'd like to override it if I can and make sure my JVM and Compiler are both using the same version.

Comment: What is the output of `which java` and `which javac`?

Comment: each command points to `/usr/bin/java` and `/usr/bin/javac` respectively and I subsequently see that those locations are specified in the `PATH` variable as it is specified in `/etc/environment`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with your last paragraph

> Can you tell me where IcedTea6 is most likely set up on Ubuntu? I'd like to override it if I can and make sure my JVM and Compiler are both using the same version.

Ubuntu provides a nice tool to select one JDK/JRE from multiple installations. This is `update-java-alternatives`. It is closely tied to the `update-alternatives` tool.

Each JDK/JRE includes a set of java tools like `javac`, `java`, `javaws`, `jinfo`, `javah` etc. An installation may come with a hidden `.jinfo` file where these java components are listed. In my system, when I install the `openjdk-8-jdk` package, a file `/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo` is created. The content of that file is (skipped some lines)

```
name=java-8-openjdk-amd64
alias=java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
priority=1081
section=main

hl rmid /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmid
hl java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
hl keytool /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
hl jjs /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jjs
hl pack200 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/pack200
hl rmiregistry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmiregistry
.
.
. (skipped lines)
.
.
jdkhl jdb /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdb
jdkhl serialver /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/serialver
jdkhl wsgen /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsgen
jdkhl jcmd /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jcmd
jdk appletviewer /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/appletviewer
jdk jconsole /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole
plugin mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

`update-java-alternatives` uses this file to create alternatives links in `/etc/alternatives` directory. The purpose of this directory is to provide a mechanism by which you can select a default program from a set of similar tools. This is great for multiple versions of JDK (see more in [`update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html))

#### Brief discussion of `update-alternatives`

To demonstrate the process briefly. When a program is first installed it registers its alternatives for a master name (like `javac`) in alternatives database (This is contained in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives` directory). During the installation process, `update-alternatives` creates a master link in `/usr/bin/javac` pointing to `/etc/alternatives/javac`, which is also a symlink pointing to the actual file from the JDK.

Now, When you install another JDK, this too will have a `javac` program. So, while installing the second JDK `update-alternatives` automatically updates the `/etc/alternatives/javac` symlink to point to the one with highest priority . It also updates the alternatives database, so that you can manually select a default by calling it.

#### Back to the `update-java-alternatives`

`update-java-alternatives` uses `update-alternatives` to provide a whole set defaults from a single JDK/JRE installation. The idea is you will select a JDK/JRE installation and all tools from that JRE/JDK will be used as default for providing multiple java tools, saving you from using `update-alternatives` for each tool. So, when you use `update-java-alternatives` to select a JDK, say `openjdk-8-jdk` for example, it makes the java tools of this JDK (such as `javac`, `java`, `javaws` etc) as default. ***Provided that the JDK is installed correctly and it lists its tools in `.jinfo` file***.

#### TL;DR

So, to answer your query in short, IcedTea6 Plugin is configured in the `.jinfo` file and `update-java-alternatives` uses that file to update the links to point to it. So, you need to create a file for your JDK listing the plugin and all java tools and use `update-java-alternatives`.

If you installed JDK/JRE manually, check this question to get help making it recognized by the `update-java-alternatives` tool.

- [How do I make java default to a manually installed JRE/JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk/159590#159590)

---

#### But we still have problems...

It seems this `update-java-alternatives` is not updating JDK components anymore lately. It's only updating JRE's tools. There are lots of complaints saying using this tool doesn't update all java components. After experiencing the same problem and spending almost 5 hours on it, I think I've found a fix. The solution is just changing `hl` to `jre` and `jdkhl` to `jdk` in `.jinfo` file. I've found [an old `.jinfo` file on github](https://gist.github.com/cwchien/1114515) where those were `jre` and `jdk`.

#### The fix for `.jinfo` file.

So, To fix it use you need to change `hl` and `jdkhl`s. If your file is `.openjdk-8-jdk.jinfo` in `/usr/lib/jvm/` use this command

```
sudo sed -i 's/^hl/jre/p' /usr/lib/jvm/.openjdk-8-jdk.jinfo
sudo sed -i 's/^jdkhl/jdk/p' /usr/lib/jvm/.openjdk-8-jdk.jinfo
```

Now to update, first list the alternatives

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

It will return something like this (the actual reply may be different for you)

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
jdk1.8.0_65                    1081       /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_65
```

Copy the alternative name from the first column and use it to set default. To set `jdk1.8.0_65` as default I'd use

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s jdk1.8.0_65 -v
```

Now, check the `java` and `javac` version.

Answer (score 0):

My PATH is in some way influenced by the file `/etc/environment` as you can see:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

When I execute `which java` and `which javac` I see something like follows:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Now, I can't be sure the two are related.* but as a Java dev I'm often adding things to Path - it's how we influence CLASSPATH so that our Java classes are available. And in the Path configuration above you see this excerpt:

```
PATH="/usr/l...sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi..."
```

I don't know what that means. Nevertheless by following the targets given to me by the `which` command I come to a set of links to executables. Looking at the targets of those links I get something like:

```
/etc/alternatives/java
```

Unsure on next steps. Copy those links, back them up or remove them. A bit of trial and error and Googling are the next steps. I haven't googled the difference between `javac -version` and `which` but I should

HTH and thanks to [BryceAtNetwork23](https://askubuntu.com/users/46270/bryceatnetwork23)

Comment: I wasn't gonna suggest that, but tbh it doesn't make any sense to me! (that's probably just me though)  Anyway, it's an "unanswered" question at the moment, so it's nice for the site if you tidy it up somehow :)

Comment: You mean my comment wasn't the best implementation of a suggestion? Happy to chat if you want! I don't want to flag for a mod since you can easily fix it yourself :)

Comment: Crowie, Most of this answer seems to me like an update to your question. I didn't explain your question, that is how javac is being set. Do you have updates to add to this answer?

Comment: Agreed. It was a rolling update and can be seen as a form of wiki type answer that is easy to flag for deletion. I have a different focus presently and so not intending to update within the next two weeks. I've kept it in its current form as have not needed to return to it within the last year except on odd infrequent occasion. It is also a highly documented topic.

Comment: I believe I also had it as the accepted answer at one point but unselected my answer as I didn't think it was sufficient personally.

Comment: @Crowie I've added another answer. Hope you will find that one helpful

Comment: "haven't googled the difference between javac -version and which but I should":  which: determine the path to the executable & return it. (NB: might itself be a symlink), javac -version : ask the executable to tell you what version it is.

Comment: Path on linux is just colon separated & a few scripts (eg, /etc/environment) set this globally before your local scripts (eg .bashrc or whatever) gets to change it. Should be deterministic though.